# For jQuery, fields inside widget box that was supposed to be removed still showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

So I have a widget foldable box function (Metadata Widget) where it displays certain fields. I have an import button off to the side where it calls upon that Metadata Widget and displays it. If I click on the import button (on a different link), certain fields in that Metadata widget are gone (which is what I want). However, if I click on a link that implements that same Metadata Widget function, and then I click the import button off to the side, all the fields in that import window shows all the fields that I want gone.

But on a different link, and if I click on the import button, the fields are gone. So how can I make sure that the fields that I want stay gone whenever I click on the import button and that I'm on the link where it shows the Metadata Widget function with ALL of the original fields?

I know this sounds convoluted, but any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<div class = "widgetPanel containerWidgetPanel foldableBox">
    <div class="boxBody">
        <table class="widgetTable containerWidgetTable">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
                  <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
                  <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
                  <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
               </tr>
               .....
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the import_box.html file, I added this script globally:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(0).remove();
    jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(0).remove();
    jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(2).remove();
    jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(2).remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though  tag does not necessary need a closing tag, I would still first add that. Instead of

```
<td class="boldColumn containerLabel">

<td class="boldColumn containerLabel"></td>
```

Then try to add your javascript code in jQuery ready function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(0).remove();
     jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(0).remove();
     jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(2).remove();
     jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(2).remove();
});
```

Or check if jQuery is loaded

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
       // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work... And I can't modify the file that has all the classes. I can only modify the .html file that has the jQuery script in it.

Answer (score 0):

After running this part of the code:

```
jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(0).remove();
jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(0).remove();
```

You are going to have only 2 more trs with those td classes since you removed the first one. Then when it takes the second part:

```
jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(2).remove();
jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(2).remove();
```

It will look for the third group that does not exist.

In order to have you desired effect, invert the order of deletion, doing that:

```
jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(2).remove();
jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(2).remove();
jQuery( "td.containerLabel" ).eq(0).remove();
jQuery( "td.containerField" ).eq(0).remove();
```